# Getting an attribute from Text String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a text string from a database and I need to access the value of an attribute from its parent element.

String:`<p lang="en" langDirection="rtl">Stuff and Things</p>`

I need to get the value of `langDirection` from the above mentioned code. It should always be the first instance of it so I don't need to search the string globally.

I achieved what I needed for my PHP parts of code using the following:

```
<?php preg_match('/langDirection="(.+?)"/', $request->requestDescription, $matches); echo $matches[1]; ?>
```

Can anyone recommend a way to do this with JS/jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple using jQuery:

```
 var strFromServer = '<p lang="en" langDirection="rtl">Stuff and Things</p>';
 $(strFromServer ).attr('langDirection');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the method below.

```js
var $theAttr = $("p").attr("langDirection");
alert($theAttr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p lang="en" langDirection="rtl">Stuff and Things</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `parseHTML` as well:

```
var el = $.parseHTML("<p lang=\"en\" langDirection=\"rtl\">Stuff and Things</p>");
console.log($(el).attr("langDirection"));
```

more info: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/